# Implementing a responsive side menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on a web page of a project. The Project had another Software Engineer and I have been continuing to the web page after he left. The problem is, he prefered side menu instead of a navbar using left-panel and right-panel method. It looks good on desktop but when you reduce the width to a mobile size, the side menu disappears and you can only see right-panel.

So, I thought that I can handle this problem by using a navbar which I used on my self learning project. (https://orcungurer.github.io/tindog) Hope sending url of it is not forbidden. This navbar turns to a hamburger menu when you turn it to mobile.
I have done a navbar just like the url but I could not implement it to the project because that left-panel and right-panel thing prevented me. Like, navbar fits the left-panel he declared but stays behind the right panel. I am really sorry if I mentioned my problem too abstract but the reason is it is also too abstract for me.. There are too many .html files and I couldn't fully adapt to these.

The navbar menu I implemented is this: https://www.codeply.com/go/tIsplp6WuY

It didn't go as I expected. So, the think I want to do when on desktop, I want to keep the site as he did but when it turns to a mobile size, I want to make a slightly different menu. As I tried, hamburger navbar menu. All of your opinions are important to me, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I somewhat got your concern theoretically but it wouldn't be helpful to understand your issue. So it would be great if you could share some demo on Codepen, JSFiddle, etc.

Comment: The demo of the server side right? If so, it would not work online, we can't see because it's like 20 html files are linked.. That's why I can only show the CodePly demo I performed..

Comment: I got you, but for better solution, it is necessary to understand your scenario to make it work. Hope you understand.

Comment: Yes, I get it.. I hope to find a way to share demo with you, wish I could share the photos of desktop and mobile size..